# Ionic iOS 10 Issue: Failed to load webpage with error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ios10

## I have this issue with `ionic` when I `run` on a device with `iOS 10`.

This issue does not happen when I'm using `--livereload`

This issue does not happen on devices that are `iOS 11`

Each time I open my app it presents me with this error `Failed to load webpage with error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.`

**`xCode` gives me this error log:**

```
2018-07-26 12:47:42.992859 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.3 is starting.
2018-07-26 12:47:42.993464 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2018-07-26 12:47:43.005162 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2018-07-26 12:47:43.066966 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2018-07-26 12:47:43.067084 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] Using Ionic WKWebView
2018-07-26 12:47:43.067705 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] [CDVTimer][console] 0.093937ms
2018-07-26 12:47:43.067900 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.102997ms
2018-07-26 12:47:43.070127 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] Unlimited access to network resources
2018-07-26 12:47:43.070232 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 2.179027ms
2018-07-26 12:47:43.070364 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.062943ms
2018-07-26 12:47:43.086203 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 15.730023ms
2018-07-26 12:47:43.086310 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2018-07-26 12:47:43.087343 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 1.037002ms
2018-07-26 12:47:43.087429 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 19.853950ms
2018-07-26 12:47:43.601648 TiTo - Talent in Talent out[25140:1448259] Failed to load webpage with error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.
```

Now I've tried removing all plugins and only left what is left on a default `ionic start myApp <template_here>`. It still provided me with the same issue on iOS 10

Here is my `ionic info` output:

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
ios-sim    : 6.1.2
Node       : v8.10.0
npm        : 6.1.0
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

## Any solutions as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. Turned out that my system was missing an entry for `localhost` in the /etc/hosts file. Adding that fixed it.

The reason this is a problem is because Cordova doesn't use file:// URLs on iOS to load the web view with the app – it uses a builtin web server accessed via http://localhost:8080.

Comment: Wow, thanks! After hours of intense googling this was the solution that worked :) Tip for others: simulators share the /etc/hosts file with your mac, so just add the following line to your mac's /etc/hosts file: `127.0.0.1 localhost`